# Show that the function $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$ is one-to-one

Tags: functions

Show that the function $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$ is one-to-one.

I know that for showing that a function is one-to-one I have to prove that if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$.

Then I'm trying that in here but I get stuck.

$$f(a)=f(b)$$
$$a+\sqrt{a}=b+\sqrt{b}$$
$$a-b=\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}$$

How to do I show from here that $a=b$?

I've tried square both sides, completing the square and haven't worked. :(

I will appreciate a detail to understand, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: think of $a-b$ like $x^2-y^2$ where $x=\sqrt{a}$ and $y=\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get the hint. :-(
You mean this:
$(\sqrt{a})^2-(\sqrt{b})^2=\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}$. 
Where I go from there?

Comment: You can factor $a-b$ as $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})$. Then if $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}\neq 0$ you can divide both sides by it to get $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=-1$ which is impossible since $\sqrt{a}\geq 0$ and $\sqrt{b}\geq 0$. Thus it must be that $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = 0$, and $a=b$ follows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Picking up from your last step, assuming $ a, b \neq 0$, we have
\begin{align*}
a - b = \sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} & \iff (a - b)(\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a}) = b - a \\
& \iff (a - b)(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + 1) = 0 \\
& \iff a - b = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + 1 = 0 \\
& \iff a = b \quad \text{(Since $ \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + 1 \neq 0 $ for any $ a $ or $ b $)}
\end{align*}
So all in all we have $ f(a) = f(b) $ if and only if $a = b $ or $ a = b = 0$, or we can absorb the latter condition into the former one and says $ f(a) = f(b) $ if and only if $ a = b$.

Comment: So we have to multiply $(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a})$ in both sides. Then in the right side there is a square difference factoring and that's how we get $b-a$. Right? Then I don't understand what happened after that. How it is get $(a-b)(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+1)=0$? I'm sorry this proofs are not that simple for me.

Comment: What happens next is just that I add $ a - b $ on both sides, then we have on the left hand side $ (a -b) (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}) + (a - b) $, so we can factor out $ a - b$ and obtain $ (a - b) ((\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}) + 1) = (a - b) (\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + 1)$.

Comment: Ohh ok. Now makes sense. Thanks. ♥

Answer (score 7):

You should always state the domain when asking any question about a function.  In this case, however, I think we can assume the domain is non-negative reals.

One easy way to prove $f$ is one-to-one is to note that both $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=\sqrt x$ are increasing functions (on the non-negative reals) - just think of their graphs - and hence so is their sum $f$.  Therefore $f$ is one-to-one.

---

If you need more detail: suppose $a\ne b$.  By symmetry we may assume $a<b$.  Therefore $\sqrt a<\sqrt b$, so $a+\sqrt a<b+\sqrt b$.  That is, $f(a)<f(b)$; and hence $f(a)\ne f(b)$.

We have shown: if $a\ne b$, then $f(a)\ne f(b)$.  Equivalently, if $f(a)=f(b)$ then $a=b$.  So $f$ is one-to-one.

IMHO this is better than doing the algebra (at least in this case).  Thinking it through this way should be much faster than writing out all the equations.

Comment: I'm sorry I've never seen a injective proof using the fact that they are increasing functions or using inequalities. Didn't understand it. :-(

Comment: Hope I don't sound rude but I think you are giving up too easily.  How about seeing if you can explain by drawing a graph why $g(x)=x$ is one-to-one?  No algebra allowed - pictures ok, words ok, nothing else.  Then come back to this and have another think.

Comment: I'm not. I just hard learning by myself things professor should teach before asking to do it. I wish I could show that function is one-to-one by graphing, would be easy to graph and do the horizontal line. But probably that's not the way prof want it. So you mean that because is increasing all the time, then will pass horizontal line test?

Comment: Please don't let your teachers insist that you **have to** do mathematics their way!!!!

Comment: Re: increasing therefore will pass horizontal line test, yes, that's exactly what I mean.  Now can you draw the graph for $h(x)=\sqrt x$ and explain why that is also one-to-one?

Answer (score 5):

$f(x) = x + \sqrt x$

We have to show that the function $f$ is injective.

let $f(a) = f(b)$

$a + \sqrt a = b + \sqrt b$

$a - b = \sqrt b - \sqrt a $

Think of $a$ as $(\sqrt a)^2$ and same for $b$.

$(\sqrt a)^2 - (\sqrt b)^2 = \sqrt b - \sqrt a$

Use the difference of squares identity.

$(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) = \sqrt b - \sqrt a$

From here, we can split this into $2$ cases.

Case 1 : $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b) \not = 0$

Then we can divide by it on both sides to get

$\sqrt a + \sqrt b = -1$.

But we know that this is not possible.

Hence, we get no solutions from this case.

Case 2 : $(\sqrt a - \sqrt b) = 0$

$\implies \sqrt a = \sqrt b$

$\implies a = b $

So the only solution we get for $f(a) = f(b)$ is $a =b$.

Hence we can say that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 2):

$$a,b >0 \implies \sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}>0$$
Next $$a-b =\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a} \implies (\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}$$
$$\implies (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+1)=0 \implies (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})=0\implies a=b.$$ As sum of $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$ and 1 cannot be zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by showing the function is increasing. Once you know $f$ is increasing, then suppose $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a\lt b$. But then because $f$ is increasing, $f(a)\lt f(b)$, a contradiction.

And there is a similar contradiction when $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a\gt b$.

So the only conclusion is that when $f(a)=f(b)$, $a$ must equal $b$.

---

Now how do we know $f$ is increasing? If $a\lt b$, then $a+\sqrt{a}\lt b+\sqrt{a}$. And then as long as we know $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is increasing, we can move on to write $a+\sqrt{a}\lt b+\sqrt{b}$. This is the defintion for $f$ to be increasing.

---

Now how do we know $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is increasing? I'm not sure how deep down into fundamentals you need to reach. But there are several ways to establish that. I'll leave this answer at this much.